# I'm not getting any OnPaint events for my panels

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a panel containing a panel which contains a panel which contains several labels.
I get an OnPaint event for the outer panel and the labels but not for the intervening panels.
What's going on??

Update: My tracing was wrong when the ClipRectangle was Size(0,0) which happens for an entirely overlain panel.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting an OnPaint event from your inner-most Panel - not the outer-most?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A paint event is raised whenever there is a part of a control that needs repainting. Areas of a control that are covered up by another (opaque) control are obscured by that control, so logically won't need to be repainted. Thus, if your panels are entirely covered up by their child controls, they may never raise Paint events.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case for all of them.
I'm interested in the top panel as the parts of its background where the labels will go first appear black and I don't like that.

Comment: The hidden panels actually do get an OnPaint event with a ClipRectangle that has zero width and height.  My tracing was in error!